# VBA Works on Sheets 2-15, but not Sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code linked to a button on sheet1, and it is designed to copy the content of Sheet3, from Row 3 until the end of the data.  If I manually run the code while my active sheet is anywhere else in the workbook it runs correctly and copies and pastes approximately 1200 rows, however if I run this from the button on sheet1 or manually when Sheet1 is my active sheet, it only copy and pastes 30 rows.  Any clue why?

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A3:F3" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets("Sheet15").Range("I2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here

```
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Macro get Range of Active Sheet. You need show to macro, which range you mean, like

```
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```